# Why is := faster than `:=`()?

Tags: r, data.table

Usually, I use the functional form `` `:=`() `` to compute multiple columns in a `data.table`, thinking that this is the most efficient method. But I've recently discovered that it's slower than simply repeatedly using `:=`. At least on my computer.

I'm guessing that there might be some overhead with the functional form of `:=` but is that the entire reason why it's slower? I'm simply asking out of curiosity in order to understand the internals of `data.table` better.

```r
library(data.table)


n <- 5000000
dt <- data.table(a = rnorm(n),
                 b = rnorm(n),
                 c = rnorm(n))

dt_a <- copy(dt)

system.time({
  dt_a[, d := a + b]
  dt_a[, e := b + c]
  dt_a[, f := a + c]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.076   0.060   0.136

dt_b <- copy(dt)

system.time({
  dt_b[, `:=`(d = a + b,
              e = b + c,
              f = a + c)]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.096   0.116   0.211
```

## Update:

One interesting property of this is that the time difference between `:=` and `` `:=`() `` is relative at about a factor of 1.5 to 2. If this was simply due to function overhead, as some suggest, I would suspect the time difference to be a fixed value?

```r
library(data.table)


n <- 20000000
dt <- data.table(a = rnorm(n),
                 b = rnorm(n),
                 c = rnorm(n))

dt_a <- copy(dt)

system.time({
  dt_a[, d := a + b]
  dt_a[, e := b + c]
  dt_a[, f := a + c]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.163   0.208   0.371

dt_b <- copy(dt)

system.time({
  dt_b[, `:=`(d = a + b,
              e = b + c,
              f = a + c)]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.284   0.404   0.688
```

Comment: On my system it's reversed. I get faster time for the second way

Comment: Given @Sotos experience, and that you seem to only have one timing there, have you tried using a tool like [`microbenchmark`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html)?

Comment: Microbench on my machine yielded mean 122:205 ms in order OP proposed, also spread is larger wirh `:=`.

Comment: Usually the most efficient method for such operations would be using `set`. Regarding you comparison- it doesn't makes much sense as `:=` and `\`:=\`` should be exactly the same function as would `(` and `\`(\`` be. While you real overhead is supposed to come from calling `data.table:::\`[.data.table\`` 3 times instead of once.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm not so sure it's _identical_ since `:=` isn't _really_ a function -- it's entirely handled with NSE. so it's possible one version gets matched, branched and handled quicker than the other (though I'd expect the reverse of OP's timings if so because LHS of := must be `eval()`'d). you're of course right that the `[` overhead is probably the driving factor, and if you want bare-metal speed `set` is the way to go... I'm just nitpicking.

Comment: what about `c("d", "e", "f") := .(..., ..., ...)` ?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yeah, I was suspecting that they might not being identical as `:=` isn't actually a data.table function rather comes from R internals, but I thought data.table created a method for it. I was looking for that in the source code but still not sure where is is supposed to be.

Comment: @Henrik I think Micahel is suggesting that `\`:=\`` is a data.table function that is getting evaluated while `:=` is just an R operator (not really coming from data.table rather being "abused" by it)- hence the overhead despite the overhead of calling `data.table:::\`[.data.table\`` 3 times

Comment: @Henrik It's fine, I'm also confused. I guess we will need to summon the Matt soon.

Comment: @duckmayr If I use `microbenchmark` I get the same results `:=` is consistently twice as fast as `:=()`. I'll try this on a different system later - the benchmarks above are with RStudio Server on Ubuntu.

Comment: One interesting property is that when I increase the data size `:=` is consistently about twice as fast as `:=()`. If this was only due to the overhead of calling a function I would suspect the difference in timings to be constant. Eg. if I increase the data size to 20.000.000 I get 336 ms for `:=` and 654ms for  `:=()`.

Comment: if you find the definition of `:=` in the data.table source you'll see it's simply defined as an error. that's how calling it outside of `[` consistently fails. inside `[` we look for `:=` in the `j` expression and continue accordingly

Comment: after first look at the code I see there seems to be extra checks there. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/589edcabd2e5cb2c1f349a84163b5aa4bd6ad7f7/R/data.table.R#L1001

Comment: Some simpler but equally confusing comparisons here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46546961#46546961

Answer (score 2):

Some timings:

```
bench::mark(
    chaining = DT0[, d := a + b][, e := b + c][, f := a + c],
    assign = DT1[, c("d", "e", "f") := .(a+b, b+c, a+c)],
    assign2 = DT1.1[, `:=` (d, a + b)][, `:=` (e, b + c)][, `:=` (f, a + c)],
    use_set = {
        set(DT2, NULL, "d", DT2[["a"]]+DT2[["b"]])
        set(DT2, NULL, "e", DT2[["b"]]+DT2[["c"]])
        set(DT2, NULL, "f", DT2[["a"]]+DT2[["c"]])
    },
    functional = DT3[, `:=`(d = a + b, e = b + c, f = a + c)]
)
```

timings and memory usage:

```
  expression     min    mean  median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result           memory      time   gc       
  <chr>      <bch:t> <bch:t> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>           <list>      <list> <list>   
1 chaining     180ms   180ms   180ms   180ms      5.54     458MB     1     1      180ms <data.table [20~ <Rprofmem ~ <bch:~ <tibble ~
2 assign       320ms   320ms   320ms   320ms      3.12     916MB     1     1      320ms <data.table [20~ <Rprofmem ~ <bch:~ <tibble ~
3 assign2      188ms   188ms   188ms   188ms      5.33     458MB     1     1      188ms <data.table [20~ <Rprofmem ~ <bch:~ <tibble ~
4 use_set      322ms   323ms   323ms   323ms      3.10     916MB     0     2      645ms <data.table [20~ <Rprofmem ~ <bch:~ <tibble ~
5 functional   331ms   331ms   331ms   331ms      3.02     916MB     1     1      331ms <data.table [20~ <Rprofmem ~ <bch:~ <tibble ~
```

data:

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.12.2  
set.seed(0L)
n <- 2e7
DT <- data.table(a=rnorm(n), b=rnorm(n), c=rnorm(n))
DT0 <- copy(DT)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT1.1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)
```